# How do I format a timespan to show me total hours in MVC with DisplayFormat

Tags: razor

I want to display the total number of hours in a TimeSpan in a list.

The code below only shows the hours part in the TimeSpan as eg. `01:30:00` but I want `25:30:00`. I using the Razor engine.

```
[DisplayName("Operating")]  
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:hh\\:mm\\:ss}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]  
public TimeSpan OperatingTime { get; set; }
```

cshtml part

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OperatingTime)
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: MVC is a pattern, not a specific language or implementation. So please tag this appropriately with what you are actually using there.

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Use this one may be it's works

```
[DisplayName("Operating")] [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{HH:mm:ss}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)] public TimeSpan OperatingTime { get; set; }
```

Comment: That solution generate exception System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'